# Timeseries data modelling in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to store & retrieve data in cassandra in the following way:

**Storing Data:**
I created the table in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE mydata (
    myKey TEXT,
    datetime TIMESTAMP,
    value TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (myKey,datetime)
);
```

Where i would store a value for every minute for last 5 years. So it stores 1440 * 365 * 5 = 2628000 records/columns per row (myKey as row key).

```
INSERT INTO mydata(myKey, datetime, value) VALUES ('1234ABCD','2013-04-03 07:01:00','72F');
INSERT INTO mydata(myKey, datetime, value) VALUES ('1234ABCD','2013-04-03 07:02:00','72F');
INSERT INTO mydata(myKey, datetime, value) VALUES ('1234ABCD','2013-04-03 07:03:00','72F');
```

.................

I am able to store data and all fine. However, i would like to know, if this is efficient way of doing (storing) data horizontally (2628000 values for each key for 1 million such keys altogether) ?

**Retrieving Data:**

After storing the data in above format, i am able to select data by using a simple select query for a period.
Ex:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mydata 
WHERE myKey='1234ABCD' AND datetime > '2013-04-03 07:01:00' AND datetime < '2013-04-03 07:04:00';
```

The query works fine and i get result as expected.

However my question is:

1. How can i select only those values at certain intervals. For example, if i query data for a day, i would get 1440 values (1 for every minute). I would like to get values at every 10 minutes interval (value at every 10th minute) limiting the no. of values to 144.
2. Is there a way to query the table if we use the above storage strategy?
3. If not, what are possible options to meet my requirement of querying data at a specific interval like 1-min, 10-min, 1-hour, 1-day etc?

Appreciate any other suggestions.

Comment: not sure I understand what you want to query. you want results from all key in a given interval?

Comment: if i use the following query, i am expecting 144 values (value at every 10th minute) instead of 1440 (value at every 1 minute). How do i query or How do i model?

SELECT * 
FROM mydata 
WHERE myKey='1234ABCD' AND datetime > '2013-04-03 07:01:00' AND datetime < '2013-04-04 07:01:00';

I am querying for 24 hours for a specific key.

Comment: do you expect any kind of range, or just every tenth?

Comment: Any kind of range would be great. It would be dynamic based on my requirement.

Comment: I don't think you can have one data model for such a wide case. however, you could consider doing programmatically. for your example, you can set 144 reads for every time you want. It might be faster than scanning a whole partition, but I don't really know

Answer (score 2):

No it not right ,in future you will face problem because per row key we can only store 2 billion records or columns. After that it will not give error but it will store data also . 
For your problem split column timestamp into  year , month , day and time .
like 2016 , 04 , 04 and 15:03:00 .Put also year , month , day into partition key .

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to bound your partition with a modular version of the timestamp. But the granularity really depends on your reads.

If you are mainly going to read per day then use something like this PK((myKey, yyyymmdd), time)

If mainly by weeks PK((mykey, yyyyww), time), or month...

The problem is then if you want to read values for a whole year, then you better have a partition per weeks or month, or even year would do I think if you don't do any deletes, your partition size needs to be smaller than 100MB

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

My row size would be fixed and would not increase any further.

Duration in my query can be hours, days, weeks, months, year etc. I want to restrict the no. of values returned by the query to a fixed number (say 100) for any duration i query.

For Ex: If i query a day data, i get 1440 records. If i want to restrict to 100, i would probably need value at every 15 minute interval (means value at every 15th minute which means value at every 15th column).

Is this really possible? If not, what is the better way of modelling for this requirement.

Comment: I don't think you can exactly restrict the number of a query results the way you want.

Comment: I would create a similar table PK((mykey, yyyymm), type, time) where type is an integer, like a 10min value is type 10, a 15min value is type 15, etc... This way you could select those specific values, would that be suitable?

Comment: The enum values of the column type doesn't really matter, you would just need to define them on client side